# where is the definition of the "struct PSI_thread" in MySQL source code?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, struct

When studying the `MySQL` source code, I found some strange structs which have not any definitions. Such as the struct `PSI_thread` in `mysql-server-code\include\mysql\psi\psi.h`. But I know there must be a definition somewhere in the source code files, otherwise it couldn't be complied. Did anyone knows where is the real definition of the struct?

The definition of the struct PSI_thread

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is an opaque struct

With [c](/questions/tagged/c), an opaque type is a structure whose content is unknown; 
Usually opaques types are declared exactly as your code show, in a header:

```
struct PSI_thread;
typedef struct PSI_thread   PSI_thread;
```

The code including the header will have some limitations:

- You don't know the object size.
- You cannot declare objects with that type directly, but you can only deal with pointers, which also means you cannot dereference them or allocate new objects.

The library ([mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) in your case) provides functions to access and handle the type itself, including allocation and deallocation.
Those functions cannot simply be inline functions since they would need to access the content of the type to work.

Opaques types **can be useful** when you need to export the interface of a library: **since you don’t know either the size or the internal ordering of an opaque type, the library can change the opaque type without changing ABI**, and thus requiring a rebuild of the software using it.

You can see it as a private context of a library, used by the library to do its job safely.

---

**EDIT**

If you cannot find a forward declaration into the whole source code, **you can see it as a `void *`**. An empty struct.

The big difference is that the empty struct it is a different type compare to other possible types and compiler can complain on type mismatch.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I know the opaque type in C. But I'm puzzled that even though I look up the struct in the whole source code project I still can not find it. I think the real definition of the struct must be somewhere in the source code files(.h file, .cc file or .cpp file), isn't it?